# How can I add parent references to Boost.Proto expressions?

Tags: c++, expression-templates, boost-proto

I want to generate expression trees that have "reverse" references from child to parent.  Is there a way to customize the Proto generator or domain so that the expression wrapper class (using `proto::extends<>`) contains a reference to the parent expression?

The goal behind this is to create expression trees that cache evaluated results, so that they can be re-evaluated efficiently.  My strategy is to update terminal values, and then walk up the tree marking parent nodes as "dirty" so that they will be re-evaluated when the root expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique you describe can't work. Expressions are built bottom-up. For the expression `a + (b * c)`, the parent node (`+`) doesn't exist at the time the child node (`b * c`) is constructed. The child can't store a pointer to an object that doesn't exist yet.

You would have to post-process expressions to set the parent pointers using a transform or context.

Comment: Thanks!  Seems obvious now, but was less so while I was lost in the meta-programming jungle :-)